# php - can't insert new record into SQLite database

Tags: php, sqlite

Here I got 2 php pages:

**createDB.php**

```
<?php
    $db = @sqlite_open("test.db");
    if (!$db) die("Connection failed./n");
    @sqlite_query($db, "CREATE TABLE foo (bar varchar(20))");
    @sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('record 1')");
    $result = @sqlite_query($db, 'select bar from foo');
    print_r(sqlite_fetch_array($result));
?>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
    $db = @sqlite_open("test.db");
    if (!$db) die("Connection failed./n");
    @sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('record 2')");
    $result = @sqlite_query($db, 'select bar from foo');
    print_r(sqlite_fetch_array($result));
?>
```

**createDB.php** does its job well,that is the test.db is created ,the foo table is created and a record 'record 1' is inserted into the foo table.

but **insert.php** doesn't do what it is supposed to do. No new record (here the value is 'record 2') will be inserted into the table.

What can go wrong? please help.

Comment: Remove all of your `@` error suppression operators - you should only turn off error reporting in your live environment, never in your dev - and never this way. Use your ini settings instead. Also, I expect `sqlite_query` will return a boolean success value - if it is false, why not use a `sqlite_` function to print the last error?